# Слово "овощ"

Tags: этимология

Можно я опять с этимологией? Какое происхождение слова "овощ"?

Answer (score 5):

Это слово заимствовано из старославянского языка.  Того же корня, что нем. wachsen "расти", лит. áugu "расту" и т. д. В древнерусском  овочь, украинском овоч, польском owoc. Овощ буквально — "то, что растет", "растение"

Comment: Это вы Шанского цинируете?
Фасмер родство с немецким "wachsen" дает с пометой "возможно", а уж прямое родство с растением и вовсе исключает.